# Подключение к почтовому ящику отключённого пользователя при помощи API EWS

Tags: c#, api, ews

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно подключиться при помощи API EWS к почтовому ящику отключённого пользователя (сервисный почтовый ящик), права на который имеет другой пользователь.

Что надо прикрутить к данному методу?

```
private static ExchangeService connect(ExchangeService service, string user, string pass, string domain, string server) //User - пользователь имеющий права на ящик, password - его пароль
{
    if (domain != "")
    {
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);
    }
    else
    {
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    }
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    Uri url = new Uri(@"https://" + server + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    service.Url = url;
    return service;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поковырявшись в англоязычном стаковерфлоу нашёл ответ.

```
FolderId NeedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "user2@domain.ru"); //user2 - отключённый пользователь
Folder Mailbox = Folder.Bind(service, NeedMailbox);
```

Дальше уже можно в нём рыться поиском.

```
var itemView = new ItemView(1000);
var result = Mailbox.FindItems(searchFilter, itemView); //searchFilter - фильтр поиска, можно и без него
```